# Rodando múltiplas instâncias da mesma aplicação em um único Memcached Server

Tags: java, docker, memcached

Estou com um problema em aplicativos "dockerizados" e Memcached, para armazenar alguns valores, aparentemente, quando eu inicio uma nova instância do Docker, que executa um cliente Spymemcached, todos os dados amaranezados no cache são invalidados, então se eu previamente armazeneis alguns valores no cache no Nó 1 e, em seguida, inicio o Nó 2, esses valores são limpos do servidor Memcached, e finalmente, se eu armazenar os mesmos valores novamente no Nó 1 e consultá-los no Nó 2, eles serão compartilhados em ambos os nós sem perder os dados.

É o comportamento esperado? Devo usar um servidor Memcached para cada instância do client? Ou é possível compartilhar a mesma instância do servidor Memcached para múltiplos clients?

Comment: Eder, nosso idioma é o **Portugues**, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Sorry, não vi que fui redirecionado para o forum em português.